# Best way to subscribe to updates of aggregated data

Tags: c#

Assume I have a class `ComplicatedStrategy` which contains fields `Price msftPrice;`, `Price ibmPrice;` and probably other fields. Now `ComplicatedStrategy` need to be notified about updates in any aggregated `Price`. So when `msftPrice` or `ibmPrice` is changed, `ComplicatedStrategy` needs to be notified with the new value.

It would be nice if `ComplicatedStrategy` knows the source of the event, so just `something is updated but I don't know what exactly` is not good.

What should I use - `events` or `listeners` or other methods? Everything should be executed on a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution is the [Observer Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx). You attach your `ComplicatedStrategy` objects to data source(s) which will notify/update them each time a data change occurs.

The relation of the Observer Pattern and DataBinding is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126035/observer-pattern-or-databinding).